# Why does the author need to wrap a non suspend function with viewModelScope.launch?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Code A is from the project architecture-samples, you can see it [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksViewModel.kt).

The `filterItems` is a normal function, when the `private fun filterTasks` invoke the `filterItems`, it's wrapped with `viewModelScope.launch`.

In my mind, normally a suspend function maybe be fired with `viewModelScope.launch`, and the system will wait until getting a result.

Why does the author need to wrap a non suspend function with `viewModelScope.launch` ?

**Code A**

```
class TasksViewModel(
    private val tasksRepository: TasksRepository,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

  private fun filterTasks(tasksResult: Result<List<Task>>): LiveData<List<Task>> {
        // TODO: This is a good case for liveData builder. Replace when stable.
        val result = MutableLiveData<List<Task>>()

        if (tasksResult is Success) {
            isDataLoadingError.value = false
            viewModelScope.launch {                 //Why wrapped with viewModelScope.launch
                result.value = filterItems(tasksResult.data, getSavedFilterType())
            }
        } else {
            result.value = emptyList()
            showSnackbarMessage(R.string.loading_tasks_error)
            isDataLoadingError.value = true
        }

        return result
    }

    private fun filterItems(tasks: List<Task>, filteringType: TasksFilterType): List<Task> {
        val tasksToShow = ArrayList<Task>()
        // We filter the tasks based on the requestType
        for (task in tasks) {
            when (filteringType) {
                ALL_TASKS -> tasksToShow.add(task)
                ACTIVE_TASKS -> if (task.isActive) {
                    tasksToShow.add(task)
                }
                COMPLETED_TASKS -> if (task.isCompleted) {
                    tasksToShow.add(task)
                }
            }
        }
        return tasksToShow
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This function is called from the main thread (in response to a `switchMap` on another LiveData), and it launches the coroutine with `Dispatchers.Main` (the default for `viewModelScope`), so this in effect will defer the action in the coroutine until after all other current tasks in the main thread queue are finished.

Sometimes this is useful for giving a quick visual indication of something, for one frame.

In this case, the line immediately preceding the coroutine changes a LiveData for a loading indicator. So there may be a reason they want that loading indicator to have a chance to be hidden in the UI before the list view for the tasks is updated. Maybe on the UI side, this will result in a more graceful transition.

Or another possibility: there was a long-running suspend function call in that coroutine at one time, it was refactored out, and they failed to remove the coroutine. It would not be the first time I've come across an error or code smell in the examples.

Even if this is not accidental, it's the sort of case where there really needs to be a comment in the code to explain it, since it is non-obvious.